# How is the index notation for the electromagnetic potentials defined?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, conventions

I don't understand, how the $\vec{A}$ potential is defined in the covariant formulation of the Maxwell-Equations.

I am using the metric $(+,-,-,-)$.

The electric field (SI-Units) is defined as:
$$
\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}\phi-\partial_t\vec{A}.\tag{1}
$$
In index notation, I would write this as:
$$
E^i/c=-(\vec{\nabla}A^0)^i-\partial_0A^i.\tag{2}
$$
And with the definition of the 4-Gradient:
$$
E^i/c=-E_i/c=-\partial_iA_0-\partial_0A^i=\partial^iA^0-\partial^0A^i=F^{i0}.\tag{3}
$$
But this is exactly the opposite of the field tensor in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor):
$$
E_i/c=F_{0i}=-F^{0i}=F^{i0}.\tag{4}
$$

What is going wrong here?

Comment: An uncontracted tensor index can only ever be at one height; you've made your $i$ downstairs in $\partial_iA_0$ but upstairs in $\partial_0A^i$. For example, $E_i/c=\partial_0A_i-\partial_iA_0=F_{0i}=\eta_{0\mu}\eta_{i\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful with upper and lower indices.

The 4-position (with upper index) and
the [4-gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-gradient#Definition) (with lower index) are:
$$x^\mu=(ct,\vec{x}) \tag{1}$$
$$\partial_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}
=\left(\frac{\partial}{c\ \partial t},\vec{\nabla}\right) \tag{2}$$

The [electromagnetic 4-potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential#Definition) with upper index is defined as
$$A^\alpha = \left( \frac{\Phi}{c},\vec{A} \right) \tag{3}$$
and hence with lower index it is
(by [index lowering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices#Raising_and_lowering_vectors_and_covectors) with the metric)
$$A_\alpha = \left( \frac{\Phi}{c},-\vec{A} \right) \tag{4}$$

The [electromagnetic tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor#Definition) with lower indices is defined as:
$$F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu  \tag{5}$$

From this, for $\mu=0$ and $\nu=i\in\{1,2,3\}$, using (2) and (4),
and $A_i$ meaning the $i$-component of $\vec{A}$, we get
$$\begin{align}
F_{0i}&=\frac{\partial}{c\ \partial t} (-A_i)
 -\nabla_i \frac{\Phi}{c} \\
 &= \frac{1}{c} \left(-\frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t}-\vec{\nabla}\Phi \right)_i \\
 &= E_i/c
\end{align} \tag{6}$$
in agreement with Wikipedia.

<sub>In the above I have adopted the convention to use
greek indices ($\alpha,\mu,\nu\in\{0,1,2,3\}$) for 4 dimensions
and latin indices ($i\in\{1,2,3\}$) for 3 dimensions.</sub>

Comment: What I don't understand is, that when we use normal vector notation, without the index, we would simply write the components of the electric field vector as being the derivatives of the components of the vector A and gradient, Therefore I would imply that the your last formula should be E with an upper index. But that's not the case. So do we actually define the electric field vector to be a covariant vector?

Comment: @Kubrik $\vec{E}$ is a vector in 3-dimensional space, not in 4-dimensional spacetime.
In 3-dimensional space there is no real difference between upper and lower index
(because there are only $+1$ in the 3-dimensional metric).
So we can just write $\vec{E}$, $\vec{A}$ or $\vec{\nabla}$ and don't
need to distinguish between $E_i$ and $E^i$.
But in 4-dimensional spacetime there is a difference between upper
and lower indices (coming from the $+1$ *and* $-1$ in the metric).
And that's why we need to carefully distinguish between $A^\mu$ and $A_\mu$
(with $\mu=0,1,2,3$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how would we define in the equation (1) of my question if E and A in 4-dimesional spacetime should have an upper or a lower index,, since the electric field transforms as a 2-Tensor and not as a vector? Simply by definition?

Comment: @Kubrik $E$ is 3-vector, not a 4-vector.
You can write your 3-dimensional equation (1) as
$E_i=-\nabla_i\phi-\partial_t A_i$ or $E^i=-\nabla^i\phi-\partial_t A^i$.
It is the same, as said in my previous comment.
And don't confuse $A_i$ with $A_\mu$, they are not the same.